# Generating excel file from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, excel

I would like to generate an excel file from sharepoint list. Each cell should contain different attributes from the list. 
The best if it was made as an additional action on list that allows me to generate such a file. The template of the document of course can be created on a different list.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Use export to excel option.

The list will be downloaded as an excel file.
Open the file and provide your sharepoint credentials.

You are good to go.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of a kind of simple action for the user. That way, indeed should work but in case of 10000 of elements on the list, trying to generate a file based on one row, it might be a real challenge